# How can I remove a change in 1 file in 1 commit

Tags: git

I change 3 files in my git commit. I don't understand:

1. why git thinks I change in the following file? The diff shows no difference.
2. how can i remove this file change in my git commit?

   ```
   diff --git a/src/StateListener.java b/src/StateListener.java
   index 0125c44..6ba0874 100644
   --- a/src/StateListener.java
   +++ b/src/StateListener.java
   @@ -7,8 +7,8 @@ import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
   import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
   import android.util.Log;

   -public class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

   +public class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private Context mContext;
   ```

Comment: Could be whitespace differences, could be permissions differences (e.g. executable vs. non-executable)

Comment: It's moving an empty line from below the public class ... { line to above it.

Comment: @wnoise, I don't think it is, if so we would have seen another line with a - and another with a + in the diff. More likely the -line contains a lot of whitespace at the end which gets wrapped in the terminal. This however probably got lost when pasting the diff here on stackoverflow, resulting in the empty line after the -line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably a whitespace change, undo the change and `git commit --amend` it.

Alternatively do the following:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
$ git checkout -f src/StateListener.java
$ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "git checkout src/StateListener.java" to discard changes in working directory.