# File with only formatting change committed, how to remove?

Tags: git

I was working on some files and committed all of them but because of my IDE's stupid formatting rules, one of the files format got changed a little and it also got committed along with the other files and pushed to my remote branch. Now I want to remove that file alone from my branch (NOT delete it from my repo but just remove it from my commit since it doesn't add value to my commit) since there was no real change in the file. How do I do that?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020305/how-can-i-remove-a-change-in-1-file-in-1-commit

Answer (score 0):

I got this done in the following way:

```
1. git checkout <masterBranch>
2. git pull <localRepo> <masterBranch>
3. git checkout <localRepo>
4. git checkout <masterBranch> -- <location of file.filename>
```

then just add and commit.

Answer (score 0):

If the commit in question is at the tip of that branch, and you have that branch checked out:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- reformattedFile
git commit --amend reformattedFile
git push -fn
```

Assuming that last command shows Git doing what you expect, remove the `n` flag to make it actually go.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

1-Go to your branch that has unnecessary/wrong file commits:

```
git checkout <yourBranchName>
```

2-Checkout file from branch that has correct file:

```
git checkout <mainBranchName> -- <fileName with complete path>
```

3-Commit your changes:

```
git add <fileName with complete path>
git commit -m <your message>
```

4-Push changes to remote branch:

```
git push <yourBranchName>
```